# dmidecode processor-version gives one answer several times

Tags: dmidecode

the cmd command:
`dmidecode -s processor-version`
gives me the same andswer 125 times.
[image]

I want the commande to andswer only one time.

how can break the loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `| head -n 1` and it worked out.